# How to combine string constants and variables in JSON?

Tags: json, mandrill

I am having a contact form page, which sends me the email using Mandrill. I am putting the subject entered by the user in the form as the subject. But I want it to also have some constant string so that I can filter those emails. How can I do that in JSON?

Something like in java we do concatenation - subject: "Customer Query" + subject. How can I do something similiar here?

Code:

```
 'message':
  {
      'from_email': email,
      'from_name': name,
      'headers': 
       {
           'Reply-To': email
       },
      'subject': subject,
      'text': msg,
      'phone_number':phone,
      'to': [
      {
          'email':'katie1990@gmail.com',
          'name': 'Katie',
          'type': 'to'
      }]
```

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON requires that strings be delimited with `"` characters, not `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

JSON is a data format, not a programming language.

It doesn't support any form of concatenation. You'll need to handle that in a programming language that generates your JSON.